# Unwanted random (?) mix of math fonts wrt. roots

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

A strange problem occurs with https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math. I have tested various fonts and math symbols and the problem seems to be the combination of https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math and `LuaLaTeX` as the problem does not occur on `XeLaTeX`. When I replace a subset of the symbols then some symbols might be replaced seemingly randomly. This is not only undesired but also gives inconsistent surds.

The color in the MWE is just for ease of detection. 
I am running on TeXLive 2019 with newest update.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math,xcolor}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathfont{texgyrebonum-math.otf}[range={\int},Color=red]

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \sqrt{b\int}
    &\sqrt[3]{b\int}
    \sqrt[4]{b\int}
    \sqrt[n]{b\int}\\
    &\cuberoot{b\int}
    \fourthroot{b\int}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The surds are obviously not consistent, both by shape and by color. Also, the joined lines in the second line look weird but that could be an issue of my pdf viewer.

[image]

Comment: Difficult to test without an example with available fonts

Comment: @egreg any math font can be used, you actually can even use Asana-Math.otf. Basically I would say it is the standard problem with the range option. You have to reset various font dimens and datas to the main font afterwards.

Comment: @egreg You are right, my code thus was not an MWE. Ulrike is also right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick fix. But I cannot assure that all affected symbols are corrected by this. I have checked the whole document for red symbols and found none except for the desired ones.

The colors in the MWE are just for ease of detection.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math,xcolor}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathfont{texgyrebonum-math.otf}[range={\int},Color=red]
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}[range={\sqrt},Color=blue]%new

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \sqrt{b\int}
    &\sqrt[3]{b\int}
    \sqrt[4]{b\int}
    \sqrt[n]{b\int}\\
    &\cuberoot{b\int}
    \fourthroot{b\int}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Observe the comment by Ulrike Fischer:*

> Your fix is the right thing to do. You should always call the main math font again after having used the range option so that font dimens and other stuff are correct. It doesn't matter much, for which range. `\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}[range=\sum]` e.g. will work too.

Comment: Your fix is the right thing to do. You should always call the main math font again after having used the range option so that font dimens and other stuff are correct. It doesn't matter much, for which range. `\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}[range=\sum]` e.g. will work too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your comment. Will this trick fix all undesired symbols or is a manual check required?